# Enterprise wiki page content type possible in team sites?

Tags: content-type, template, enterprise-wiki

I know it sounds silly but I have tried it and it does not work.

I wanted to activate the Enterprise wiki page and Project Page (from the Enterprise wiki template) in a normal Site Pages library in a Team site where publishing features are activated.

The reason is that eventually I might want to use the page with the rating box in a normal site that is not an Enterprise wiki site.

Is the error I receive by design? I notice is it normal to add extra content types in a document library but a Site Pages library does not accept further content types that are not Web Part page or Wiki page.

I am using SharePoint online (2013)

Comment: >>`Is the error I receive by design?` - Hard to say. Maybe you could share the error you get?

Comment: the error is the usual 'something went wrong' then it gives you a log but as a office 365 user I do not get to see what it belongs to

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is interested in this discovery, I found a sort of workaround.

By chance I have a Publishing Site and I have noticed it has the Page libraries "PAGES" and "Site Pages". The latter created by activating the publishing features.

In Site Pages it does not work, but it works in the library called Pages. Why is that, I have no idea. You would think the other way around since the enterprise wiki is a publishing site.

Answer (score 0):

A site pages library differs from a document library. The Enterprise Wiki  and the Project Page are more than just a bunch of metadata columns applied to an uploaded file (like a document library's content types).

Enterprise Wiki relies on the Publishing feature and there are certain requirements and restrictions that also apply. Enterprise Wiki pages have page layouts that govern how the page columns are rendered. This functionality requires specific content types. Hence you can only add specific content types to such a library.